# KeyEvent working with Java 1.7 but not with 1.6

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

We have developed a plugin project which is developed on Java 1.7(in eclipse) and build on java 1.6(build tool is on Java 1.6, it will we upgraded to Java 1.7 soon).

We are using key listener in our code which is running fine when core application is running on Java 1.7 but not when core application is running on Java 1.6(Current production environment is running on Java 1.6 which will further migrated to java 1.7).

Any idea, what we can do for this issue?

```
txtInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            setAdjusting(cbInput, true);
            keyEvent = false;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER
             || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP
             || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
                selectionAllowed = true;
                e.setSource(cbInput);
                cbInput.dispatchEvent(e);
                keyEvent = true;
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
                 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
                    if(cbInput.getSelectedItem() != null ) {
                        txtInput.setText(cbInput.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
                    }   
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {                      
                    cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
                    if(txtInput.getText() != null ) {
                        try {
                            BFMDateTime end_date;
                            BRMap map = new BRMap();
                            map.putElem("content", txtInput.getText().trim());
                            map.putElem("action", "ButtonClicked");
                            map.putElem("start_date", timeZone.bfmDateToSearchFormat(new BFMDateTime(uiObj.fromDate.getText().toString())));
                            end_date = new BFMDateTime(uiObj.toDate.getText().toString());
                            end_date.addHours(23);
                            end_date.addMinutes(59);
                            end_date.addSeconds(59);
                            map.putElem("end_date", timeZone.bfmDateToSearchFormat(end_date));
                            CommandMsg commandMsg = new CommandMsg(AppConstants.DEALER_SEARCH_COMMAND, map);
                            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
                            requestHandler.handleRequest(commandMsg,AppConstants.RESPONSE_SOURCE,uiObj);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (BFMTimeException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                } 
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
            setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What do they say if you do?

Comment: I am not getting any error message. just VK_UP and VK_DOWN events are not getting captured while VK_ENTER is working fine.

Comment: Did you check both up / down keys, the normal cursor keys as well as the number pad? Not claiming that's the solution, but it could maybe help pointing to the problem.

Comment: Did you check whether you could, in that case, use `keyReleased` or `keyTyped` events?

Comment: All the keys are working fine and even responding when core application is running on Java 1.7, i am not sure if it is java version comparability issue.

Comment: Above code is working fine in DEV environment. As of now code is in production. Don’t mine, Can’t do hit and trail.

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).